# How to get hour from datetime-local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the hour in different ways from a `datetime-local` input but every time I've got the output as "invalid" date.

So I would like to know how can I get the hour from a `datetime-local` input using jquery or js.

Here is what I've tried:

```
var fine =  moment($('#datafine').val).format("HH");
```

And without moment that was something like

```
var datafine = new Date($('#datafine').val);
```

Comment: The issue most likely comes from the value you pass to the functions you use. What is the value of `$('#datafine').val`?

Comment: `var datafine = new Date($('#datafine').val);` close - `var datafine = new Date($('#datafine').val());`

Comment: @freedomn-m I totally get the point of the `datetime-local`, but if `new Date()` didn't work, I just assumed that the fetched then passed value was wrong, and actually, OP forgot `()` after `val` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the value from the input, it is converted to a standard format, regardless of the displayed format:

> One thing to note is that the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

So you can use this with `new Date(val).getHours()` to get the hours.

Using jQuery:

```js
var hour = new Date($('input[type="datetime-local"]').val()).getHours()
console.log($('input[type="datetime-local"]').val(), hour)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="party">Enter a date and time for your party booking:</label>
<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" value="2019-06-01T19:30">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Comment: Why does this show "2019-06-01T19:30 5" for me? The hour for 19:30 should be 19.

Comment: @RobG are you anywhere other than UTC time? (GMT if you prefer)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being obtuse. You really should never rely on the built–in parser, "2019-06-01T19:30" should be parsed as local but Safari parses it as UTC. And yes, my timezone is not GMT. :-) PS this is a seriously gratuitous use of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, something like this may help. You would just need to add in the date value from your input into new `Date()`.  The code below would give you the hours in the specified locale.

```
const date = new Date();
const options = { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric'};
const hours = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options); 

console.log(hours)
```

[Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)